# ¿Cómo puedo sustituir un simbolo con sympy sustitución a partir de un string?

Tags: python

Tengo una expresión regular e intento sustituir el símbolo `x` de un string.

```
'-{} - {}x + {}' : '-{} - {}*x + {}'
```

Por lo que `expr1` equivale a `-{} - {}*x + {}`. Cuando intento reemplazar de esa expresión regular ya generada, el símbolo `x` en el string `expr1`, por un número aleatorio, supongamos que `7`. No me permite sustituirlo:

`final = str(expr1).subs('x',sol[0])`  # `expr1` supongamos que equivale a (2*x+3) y `sol[0]` es el `7`

Por lo que intento obtener `(2*x+3)` -----> `(2*7+3)`

Cuando imprimo, no me arroja nada, ni siquiera un error.
¿Cómo puedo reemplazar con `.subs()` un caracter de un string? De antemano muchas gracias. Saludos!

Comment: En `.subs(x`, `x` es una variable, que no existe, prueba con `.subs("x"`

Comment: Ups, se me pasó, así es como lo tengo `.subs("x"`

Comment: primero reemplaza la `x` por `*x` y luego ya reemplazas la `x` por el valor numérico

Comment: Sigo en las mismas, no me imprime nada

Comment: Y si en vez de `subs()` usas cadenas de formato? (no estoy hablando de f-strings, no confundir). Por ejemplo: `expr1="(2*{x}+3)"`. En este tipo de cadenas las llaves representan el lugar donde irá un valor de una variable. El valor se insertaría así: `expr1.format(x=sol[0])` y eso generará la cadena `"(2*7+3)"`, si `sol[0]` valía 7.

Comment: Sí funciona `expr1.format(x=sol[0])`, pero me imprime `expr1` tal cual como `2*x+3`

Comment: La solución de abulafia era válida pero faltaba reemplazar la `x`, por `{}`, así que realicé `remmp = expr1.replace('x', '{}')` y utilicé `final = remmp.format(sol[0])`